# Having trouble accessing property of boolean

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm simply trying to set a boolean to true based on certain logic.

Here is my code.

My two properties are set.

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL stoneSwitch;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL cystSwitch;
```

Here is an action I've set up on a switch in my storyboard

```
- (IBAction)switcherAction:(id)sender
{
    if (self.customSwitcher.isOn) {
        if ([self.customLabel.text isEqual:@"Stone Manip"]) {
            NSLog(@"%d",self.cystSwitch);
            if (self.cystSwitch == TRUE) {
                [self.customSwitcher setOn:YES];
                self.stoneSwitch = TRUE;
            } else {
                [self.customSwitcher setOn:NO];
            }
        } else {
            self.cystSwitch = TRUE;
        }
    }

    [self.delegate updateField:self.fieldName withBoolValue:self.customSwitcher.isOn];

}

-(void)setPlaceHolder:(NSString*)placeHolder
{
    [super setPlaceHolder:placeHolder];
    _customLabel.text = placeHolder;

}
```

I log back up above my cystSwitch Boolean yet it always stay 0. What am I missing here?

EDIT ONE:

```
- (IBAction)switcherAction:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.customLabel.text isEqual:@"Stone Manip"]) {
        NSLog(@"%d",self.cystSwitch);
        if (self.cystSwitch == TRUE) {
            [self.customSwitcher setOn:YES];
            self.stoneSwitch = TRUE;
        } else {
            [self.customSwitcher setOn:NO];
        }
    } else {
        self.cystSwitch = TRUE;
        NSLog(@"%d",self.cystSwitch);
        [self.customSwitcher setOn:YES];
    }

    [self.delegate updateField:self.fieldName withBoolValue:self.customSwitcher.isOn];

}
```

I've noticed that if I log my self.cystSwitch out under the else conditional that it does reflect correctly but resets once it starts over. Is this because I am not using pointers for my properties?

Comment: what's the `self.customLabel`? does it's `text` ever get set to something besides `@"Stone Manip"`?

Comment: The custom label is always the text provided when the switch gets set up. It stays the same and I can verify that through my debugger and console to see it always gets to the log. The log always tells me 0 though.

Comment: Yeah, there are two switches called. One being @"Stone Manip" and the other "Cysto / Stent". Those two texts can be different based on which switch is called.

Comment: could you post the code where you assign the `customLabel.text` please?

Comment: There is the method used to set it.

Comment: Your switch must always be `off` when it reaches switcherAction, so just returns `0`...

Comment: So I should put this code outside of the isOn conditional it sounds like.

Comment: Yes, because it's never going to reach it as long as you enter that function with `off`. It's unclear where you are setting the On/Off otherwise. The logic of the function isn't really working either, because if it's `on` then it will never reach the `off` part... You turn it on, and on and on. :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm losing my mind haha. Thanks. I'll trying to get it to work. I'll post my code shortly.

Comment: I edited my question to show my update.

Comment: @wowzuzz: Hey don't feel bad, most everyone has probably gone through it... I know it took me a bit before it made sense — these things can be mind numbing at times.

Comment: Thanks man. I appreciate that. Learning through the days has been a slow but rewarding process.

Comment: [Here's an example of a boolean switch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049110/how-to-properly-hide-these-ad-banners/23050417#23050417) that rotates two different types of ad banners...  I would try the example in my answer and put an `NSLog()` in the if/else and run it a few times to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you setting / changing the self.cystSwitch property somewhere in the app if the code doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is likely that you are not persisting the data, have you looked at saving the information out to NSUserDefaults or using some kind of persistence like plist?

```
[NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"cystSwitch"]
```

Then read it back up when you start the app again

```
[NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"cystSwitch"]
```

---

**Sidenote:**

You should not compare using this:

```
if (self.cystSwitch == TRUE)
```

you should use

```
if (self.cystSwitch)
```

The problem is that BOOL is not a native type, but a typedef:

```
typedef signed char      BOOL;

#define YES             (BOOL)1
#define NO              (BOOL)0
```

As a char, its values aren't constrained to `TRUE` and `FALSE`.  What happens with another value?

```
BOOL b = 42;
if (b)
{
    // true
}
if (b != YES)
{
    // also true
}
```